# Does Java have a constants defined for common port numbers?

Tags: java

Is there a class that has defined constants for common port numbers like 80, 443, 21?

The only way right now I found is using `getDefaultPort` on URL that has a `http`, `https` or `ftp` schema, but it looks excessive to just get a constant.

I'm asking because I don't want to throw a bunch of magic numbers around the code and I assume there should be a place with those constants somewhere (e.g. we have one for UTF8 now).

Comment: Including common libraries or just pure JDK?

Comment: Question: why do you want to know?  Just to listen on a port?

Comment: Nope, there is none.

Comment: Not exact duplicate, I'm asking about other ports also, not only HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: I guess since these port numbers are well known, then it would be duplicating another source to make these constants in the Java API.  By which I mean most people just look up the port number they need and define their own constant.  It's not a bad thought to ask this question, but I think the Java API designers decided this was something best left to the organizations that already handle it.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of, but I am curious too. That would be nice. I know this is not an "answer," but in case you wanted to create your own, here is a table that I use (I would have put it in a comment, but I can't paste photos):

[image]